# Sorting by time, ignoring date

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I need to sort a column by time, ascending (and ignore Date). This is to create a distribution by time later on.

So I set column format to time.
Still, when I sort the column, ascending, it takes into account the Date.

How to sort column truly by Time then?

Comment: Output format cannot affect on the value. Sort by fractional part of the value (use additional column with formula `B1=A1-INT(A1)` formatted as a time, maybe hidden).

Comment: You might need to separate the time out into a new column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*With the help of few Helper Columns, your problem can be fixed.*

**Before Sort:**

[image]

- Formula in Cell `AX2`:

`=AZ2-INT(AZ2)`

- Fill formula down the apply Cell Format `HH:MM:SS`on `AX2:AX5`.
- Enter this formula in Cell `AY2`, fill it down then apply an appropriate DATE Format or `MM/DD/YY` on `AY2:AY5`.

`=INT(AZ2)`

- Select data along with Headers `AX1:AZ5`.
- From **H**ome TAB click **S**ort & **F**ilter, then **C**ustom Sort.
- Check Option **M**y Data Has Header.
- Add **L**evels to **S**ort, as shown in the Screen Shot below.

[image]

- Finish with **O**k.

**After Sort:**

[image]

**N.B.**

*The reason behind two HELPER COLUMNS (Date & Time) is, more than one entry for similar Date, which is quit natural & possible too.*

- Later on for neatness you may hide HELPER COLUMNS & you get this.

[image]

*You may adjust cell references & Date Time Cell Format as needed.*

Comment: Glad to help you @Robert Brax ,, keep asking ☺

Comment: Thank you so much for great answer.